# Function with same signature

Tags: cuda, overloading, nvcc

I would like to have two versions of same member function of a class in host and device side. 
Lets say

```
class A {  
public:  
    double stdinvcdf(float x) {  
        static normal boostnormal(0, 1);  
        return boost::math::cdf(boostnormal,x);  
    }

    __device__ double stdinvcdf(float x) {  
        return normcdfinvf(x);
    }  
};
```

But when I compile this code using nvcc, it aborts with `function redefinition` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA / C++ does not support this kind of function overloading, because in the end, there is no different function signature. The common approach to have both, i.e. `host` and `device` versions is to use `__host__` in combination with `__device__` alongside with an `#ifdef`, e.g.

```
__host__ __device__ double stdinvcdf(float x)
{
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    /* DEVICE CODE */
#else
    /* HOST CODE */
#endif
}
```

This solution was also discussed [in this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545609/overloading-__host__-and-__device__-function/) in the NVIDIA developer forum.

Comment: How very unfortunate. Makes you wish nVIDIA had a feature request form.